# getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') in php returns nothing

Tags: http

I've been trying to get the client IP address of the computers connected in LAN and if I use the getenv('REMOTE_ADDR') or $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] it returns different IP it seems that it gets the proxy address of the browser used by the computer and when I tried getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') it returns nothing and the $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] has an error which is undefined index. I've tried every possible code I found in getting the real IP address but nothing worked. Please help.

Comment: Its an optional header, have you used wireshark/fiddler or the like to verify its present in the request in the first place?

Comment: If `print_r($_SERVER)` does not reveal the IP address you're after, the server does not have that piece of info.

Comment: it is not present in the $_SERVER array does it have something to do with my php.ini or config file of xampp?

Comment: is there any other way to get the local ip address that uses a proxy address? javascript or php codes?

Answer (score 0):

One of the intended purposes of client side HTTP proxy can be hiding the internal topology of an organization.

If you control the proxy, you can set it up to reliably report the original IP address in a header, but there is no guarantee other people will do so.

As the ability to hide the topology is intentional in HTTP, you have to resort to "evil" practices like a signed applet, an activeX control, or other execution method with lax security.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a shorter, cleaner way to get the accurate IP address:**

```
function get_ip_address(){
    foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR') as $key){
        if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true){
            foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip){
                $ip = trim($ip); // just to be safe

                if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false){
                    return $ip;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's working fine..